# Forwarding to a Django site not working

Tags: django

If you go to `http://lebronjamesstats.com` you get a blank page. But if you look at the source code:

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://stats-lebronjamesstats.rhcloud.com/" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>
```

`stats-lebronjamesstats.rhcloud.com` works. Any thoughts?

Comment: `<frameset>` has been removed from HTML5 - don't use it for new projects

Comment: I think this is GoDaddy DNS servers doing this maybe. I bought the domain name with them but I'm hosting with OpenShift

Comment: Not sure if relevant but is Clickjacking Protection enabled? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/clickjacking/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forward with masking was preventing my website from working. Here was my OpenShift example: [OpenShift URL Masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717774/openshift-url-masking)