# OpenShift URL Masking

Tags: openshift

How can I get my OpenShift URL `http://stats-lebronjamesstats.rhcloud.com/` to show as  `lebronjamesstats.com`. I bought the domain name from Godaddy and setup forwarding and a CNAME record that has subdomain `www` point to `stats-lebronjamesstats.rhcloud.com`. I also ran the `alias` OpenShift commands:

```
rhc alias add stats lebronjamesstats.com
rhc alias add stats www.lebronjamesstats.com
```

I CAN'T do forward with masking because that breaks in browsers. Thanks for your help!

Dusty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get a cname record for `www` to point to my OpenShift url and then do forwarding from `lebronjamesstats.com` to `www.lebronjamesstats.com` WITHOUT masking. All HTTP request now resolve to `www.lebronjamesstats.com`. I could use a third party redirector to get `lebronjamesstats.com` to show in the URL box. I might pursue this later.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you'll need to add an "alias" to your application via the `rhc` command line tool or through the web console. Here's two resources that will show you how to do that step by step:

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/domain-names-and-ssl-in-the-openshift-web-console
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way

Comment: I ran the `rhc alias` commmand